# Group by statement to do average of time

Tags: sql, group-by

My existing database has data coming for an id, value and time. There is one record coming every 3 seconds. I want my `select` statement to use these data and group them based on id and hrly basis to show the average of the values in that hr. How can I use `group by` to achieve this ?

This is my sample data:

```
id  value   date       time
a   5       5/18/2015  10:27:22
a   9       5/18/2015  10:27:25
b   7       5/18/2015  10:27:22
b   8       5/18/2015  10:27:22
```

I have data coming in every 3 seconds. I want it to be aggregated based on every hr of the day to reflect avg values of that id in that hr.
I want the output to look like

```
id -a , gives avg of 7 , at 10 on 5/18/2015
```

Comment: Can you share the sql statements that you've tried?

Comment: Please edit your question and include (1) sample data; (2) desired results; and (3) add a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: From the information that you've provided, this sounds like a fairly basic example of using Group By and Aggregate functions.  Please provide the additional information requested and also check out [this page explaining Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Comment: will it span multiple days? and if so do you want the average per day/time or just for the same time every day

Comment: it has data for multiple days, but i will need to view it as average per day/time

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively simple group by which will have two types of columns generally. Your grouped columns and your aggregates. In this case your grouped columns will have ID,date, and hr(calculated from [time]). You only have one aggregated column in this case: the average of value. Check out my code:

```
SELECT ID,
       [date],
       DATEPART(HOUR,[time]) AS hr,
       AVG(value)            AS avg_val
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID,[date],DATEPART(HOUR,[time])
```

Answer (score -1):

This query will pull each ID along with the average value, grouped by each hour of the day. If you want to run this for more than 1 day, you would have to group by the date + the hour so 6/19/2015 10:00, then 6/19/2015 11:00 and so forth.

```
SELECT
  id,
  avg(value) AS avg_val,
  datepart(hh, time_interval) AS time_interval
FROM my_table
WHERE time_interval = '6/19/2015'
GROUP BY id, datepart(hh, time_interval)
```

To include multiple days, you could group change the group by section to be:

GROUP BY id, convert(varchar(10), time_interval, 120), datepart(hh,time_interval)

Comment: This would group records from different days together which is incorrect.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for multiple days and also put a quick description of the query.